# How to delete na values corresponding to the target variable

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data set that has too many na values, even my target variable has got null values ,I managed to handle the null values by replacing them with appropriate values but for the target variable I need to remove the rows with na values. how can I remove the observations with na values corresponding to a particular column in python?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your problem? your data? your code?

Comment: `df.dropna()` ,for columns: `df.dropna(axis=1)` ?